# WPF Dashboard best practices?

Tags: c#, wpf, dashboard

I am building a dashboard where a user can add panels and also resize and move the individually. 
Then end result might look something like this:

[image: Dashboard Example]

Basically I want it to be like Blacklight's "[drag drop panel](http://mightymeaty.members.winisp.net/blacklight.silverlight/)" but with resizable panels.

What is the best practice to use if I *don't* want to use a dock manager control? 
I thought about using a collection of user controls made of stackpanels, or some sort of grid, but
I am afraid I'm over-thinking it.

Comment: Infragistics has something like that ;)

Comment: @TomTom I didn't see it, they have cards, but it is not resizable

Comment: Why don't you want to use a dock manager control?  Something has to be responsible for managing the position of the items, and it makes sense to put the logic in its own control, whether you use a third party one or write your own.

Comment: @arx I don't like the UX of a dock manager, I want it to be more animated and intuitive